# calculate count of number observation for all variables at once in R

Tags: r

```
numbers1 <- c(4,23,4,23,5,43,54,56,657,67,67,435,
         453,435,324,34,456,56,567,65,34,435)
```

and

```
numbers2 <- c(4,23,4,23,5,44,54,56,657,67,67,435,
         453,435,324,34,456,56,567,65,34,435)
```

to peform counting i do so manually

```
as.data.frame(table(numbers1))
as.data.frame(table(numbers2))
```

but i can have 100 variables from mydat$x1 to mydat$100. 
I don't want manually enter 100 times. 
How to do that all counting would for all variables?

```
 as.data.frame(table(mydat$x1-mydat$x100))
```

is not working.

Comment: Make a data frame from both vectors and map it to `table` or just a list for unequal lengths? Try this: `Map(table,data.frame(n1 = numbers1, n2= numbers2))` Can use any of the `apply*` family of functions or the `tidyverse` packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can make a list of all variables in the environment that have a pattern like `numbers`. Then we can loop through all of the elements of the list:

```
number_lst <- mget(ls(pattern = 'numbers\\d'), envir = .GlobalEnv) #thanks NelsonGon

lapply(number_lst, function(x) as.data.frame(table(x)))

$numbers1
     x Freq
1    4    2
2    5    1
3   23    2
4   34    2
5   43    1
6   54    1
7   56    2
8   65    1
9   67    2
10 324    1
11 435    3
12 453    1
13 456    1
14 567    1
15 657    1

$numbers2
     x Freq
1    4    2
2    5    1
3   23    2
4   34    2
5   44    1
6   54    1
7   56    2
8   65    1
9   67    2
10 324    1
11 435    3
12 453    1
13 456    1
14 567    1
15 657    1
```

Comment: Thanks @NelsonGon. I knew there was a better way. We could combine your ```mget``` with your comment to OP: ```Map(table,data.frame(mget(ls(pattern = 'numbers\\d'))))```

Answer (score 1):

As I read your question, you want to count the number of times each unique element in a set occurs using minimal re-typing over many sets.

To do this, you'll first need to put the sets into a single object, e.g. into a list:

```
list_of_sets <- list(numbers1 = c(4,23,4,23,5,43,54,56,657,67,67,435,
                                  453,435,324,34,456,56,567,65,34,435),
                     numbers2 = c(4,23,4,23,5,44,54,56,657,67,67,435,
                                  453,435,324,34,456,56,567,65,34,435))
```

Then you loop over each list element, e.g. using a for loop:

```
list_of_counts <- list()
for(i in seq_along(list_of_sets)){
  list_of_counts[[i]] <- as.data.frame(table(list_of_sets[[i]]))
}
```

`list_of_counts` then contains the results:

```
[[1]]
   Var1 Freq
1     4    2
2     5    1
3    23    2
4    34    2
5    43    1
6    54    1
7    56    2
8    65    1
9    67    2
10  324    1
11  435    3
12  453    1
13  456    1
14  567    1
15  657    1

[[2]]
   Var1 Freq
1     4    2
2     5    1
3    23    2
4    34    2
5    44    1
6    54    1
7    56    2
8    65    1
9    67    2
10  324    1
11  435    3
12  453    1
13  456    1
14  567    1
15  657    1
```